# How can I pass csv row specific information to my function?

Tags: python

I am working on a script to check a csv and get the resolution of the images in the links and it then appends this info into a new csv file. I had it working, but it wasn't including headers. I found a way to add the headers, but now I don't know how to pass my size information for each row to the function when I actually call it.

When I run my script I get an error saying size is not defined (referring to the size = str(width) + " x " + str(height) line int the function def).

Error:

```
  File "image_resolution_check.py", line 38, in <module>
    lambda row, line_num: row.append(header_of_new_col) if line_num == 1 else row.append(
  File "image_resolution_check.py", line 32, in add_column_in_csv
    transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num)              
  File "image_resolution_check.py", line 39, in <lambda>
    size))
NameError: global name 'size' is not defined
```

Script:

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from csv import reader
from csv import writer

input_file = sys.argv[1]
output_file = str(input_file).replace('.csv', '') + '_Output.csv'
header_of_new_col = 'Resolution'

def get_image_size(url):
    data = requests.get(url).content
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(data))  
    return im.size

def add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, transform_row):

    with open(input_file, 'r') as read_obj, \
        open(output_file, 'wb') as write_obj:
        # Create a csv.reader object from the input file object
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        # Create a csv.writer object from the output file object
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Read each row of the input csv file as list
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[1] != 'image_num':
                width, height = get_image_size(row[1])
                size = str(width) + " x " + str(height)
            # Append the default text in the row / list
                #row.append(str(width) + " x " + str(height))
                transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num)              
            # Add the updated row / list to the output file
                csv_writer.writerow(row)


add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file,
                      lambda row, line_num: row.append(header_of_new_col) if line_num == 1 else row.append(
                          size))
```

Comment: "size is not defined" when you try return value ```return im.size```. Use try catch or try to print before to make sure has some value

Comment: @RafaelRibeiro the im.size portion works fine. I have confirmed that my test data all returns info. It is the size = str(width) + " x " + str(height) that I am trying to call in the function at the bottom that throws the error. I don't know how to prooperly pass it from the def row for loop to the actual function in use.

Comment: Could you add the full text of the error to the question? It would help understand where exactly the error occurs

Comment: @theFrok Hi, I have added the full error. Basically, it doesn't see size because it isn't a global variable and only lives in the function, but I don't know how to pass the size value for each row to the function when I call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add `size` as another argument for your lambda function.

```py
lambda row, line_num, size: row.append(header_of_new_col) if line_num == 1 else row.append(size)
```

of course than you'll have to change the call to the function and pass `size` there a well.

```py
transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num, size)
```

But this lambda function starts to get long and complicated, and maybe you'll want to use different function that only gets two argument. So what I'll recommend is extracting the lambda to a named function and performing the size calculation inside that function.

```py
.
.
.

def add_size_to_row(row, line_num):
    if line_num == 1:
        row.append(header_of_new_col)
    else:
        width, height = get_image_size(row[1])
        size = str(width) + " x " + str(height)
        row.append(size)

def add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, transform_row):

    with open(input_file, 'r') as read_obj, \
        open(output_file, 'wb') as write_obj:
        # Create a csv.reader object from the input file object
        csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
        # Create a csv.writer object from the output file object
        csv_writer = writer(write_obj)
        # Read each row of the input csv file as list
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row[1] != 'image_num':
            # Append the default text in the row / list
                #row.append(str(width) + " x " + str(height))
                transform_row(row, csv_reader.line_num)              
            # Add the updated row / list to the output file
                csv_writer.writerow(row)


add_column_in_csv(input_file, output_file, add_size_to_row)
```

Comment: I tried this and it outputed a file with size appended, but there were no column headers with it. Were you able to get that part working?

Comment: maybe your header returns true for that clause `if row[1] != 'image_num':`? so the header line is skipped?

Comment: you are exactly right. I moved that if and it now works great. Thank you!